# Hide Sulu media collection tiles when permissions don't allow viewing of that collections' media

Tags: sulu

Using Sulu 2.2.3, on the All Media page, all users can see all media collections even if a users' permissions don't allow them to see the images within the collection.

Permissions are working fine - clicking into a restricted collection correctly displays the No Permissions notice - but I'd like to hide the collection tile entirely from the user on the previous page if they are restricted from seeing the contents.

Regards my use case, I'd like to use a single Sulu instance to manage a handful of sites for separate clients, each client will have different permissions and I don't want them to see other media collections than their own.

Any suggestions would be much obliged.